# Flutter: Get Bluetooth RSSI value from iBeacon broadcast signal

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way that I can read the broadcast iBeacon RSSI value (without pairing to the beacon) using Flutter yet?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [library](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) that allows you to fetch the RSSI of any discovered Bluetooth device. Sample code:

```
var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((scanResult) {
  // do something with scan result
  device = scanResult.device;
  print('${device.name} found! rssi: ${scanResult.rssi}');
});
```